# Is it possible to hide first person blood stains in Black Mesa Source?

Tags: black-mesa

After trying out black mesa source I decided that the game has a lot of replay value, I missed many things and there are still achievements, but still the #1 thing which annoyed me the most during the game was the blood stains that you get on your hands and/or weapon when you kill an enemy. Here's a picture for reference:
[image]

Is it possible to remove it? I think it's so messy and unrealistic, and I completely despise this effect. I've looked around the settings but nothing seemed to disable this effect. I'm pretty sure it can affect performance as well.

Comment: It disappears after a bit.  I don't know if there even is a setting for that, though.

Comment: It does disappear after a minute or two, but you never stop killing, so the effect lasts for a very long time if you're in the mood for action :(

Comment: I highly doubt a few extra small textures will "affect performance" in any noticeable way.

Comment: Source games are quite moddable, so it may be possible *in theory* even without a settings option, if you have the modding knowledge to find the right file(s) and make the right alterations.

Comment: This effect was a terrible let-down for me when playing, I was getting blood stains when shooting an alien with a pistol at medium range, that was weird, not to mention the blood stained guns look weird, as if a decal glitched all over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I don't believe you can disable this effect.

Answer (score 2):

Just type

```
cl_mdldetailfx_enable 0
```

into the console.

I had the opposite problem, stains didn't appear at all, but I have re-enabled that by setting `cl_mdldetailfx_enable 1`